# Java Clipboard availability

Tags: java, netbeans, clipboard

When I research things on the internet I like to copy and paste certain paragraphs so I could review them later on.

I'm trying to write a program that would continuously check the clipboard for text content and write it to a text file any time it is renewed.

In the following test of the program I had "public class Clipboard" in my clipboard **before** running the program and the exception happened when I copied text from netbeans (The IDE I was using to run the program) while the program was running:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class TestClipboard {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        String initial = "";
        while(true) {
            try {
                String paste = c.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
                if(!paste.equals(initial)) {
                    System.out.println(paste);
                    initial = paste;
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestClipboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
public class TestClipboard
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot open system clipboard
    at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.openClipboard(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable.<init>(ClipboardTransferable.java:78)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getContents(SunClipboard.java:144)
    at delete.TestClipboard.main(TestClipboard.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 34 seconds)

**Why can't it open the system clipboard?**

**Does the getSystemClipboard() method not have global scope? - In other words, can I not get the clipboard's contents if the copy operation was performed in an internet browser?**

Comment: Rather then spamming the clipboard, consider adding a `Thread.sleep` in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to read from the clipboard while another process is updating to it (or some such).

I fixed by:

1. Requesting an instance of the `Clipboard` within the loop
2. Adding a `Thread.sleep` into the `while-loop`

For example...

```
public class TestClipboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String initial = "";
        while (true) {
            try {
                Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                String paste = c.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
                if (!paste.equals(initial)) {
                    System.out.println(paste);
                    initial = paste;
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestClipboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

It should be noted that it won't stop it from happening, it will only reduce the number of occurrences.  When it is thrown, you could (just about) ignore and try again...

Comment: Seems to have solved the problem, thanks! Did you have any particular reason to choose 40ms as the sleeping time?

Comment: Not really, usually use it for animations 25fps) ;)